# "Renewed vigor" vs. "renewing vigor"

Tags: meaning-in-context, grammar, adjectives, past-participles

> - He played with renewed vigor and determination.

Could we exchange "renewed" with "renewing"?

Renewed vigor by (someone) 
Renewing vigor by ( itself)

Vigor which is renewing vs vigor which is renewed by the person himself.

Comment: In practice, *[with] **renewed vigour*** is something of a "set expression", which in and of itself makes ***renewing vigour*** rather unlikely (also it's *semantically* a bit unusual; it's easier to imagine that the renewal was "complete" at the narrative reference time, rather than "ongoing"). With slightly different wording, such as *He played with **increased / increasing determination***, it's easier to conceptualise the intent of *either* verb form (was his determination *already* more solid when he (re-)started playing, or did it increase *while he was playing?*).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, either participle can be used adjectivally to modify **vigor**.

> It is a charged battery.
>
> It is a charging battery.

There is no implication with the past participle that the vigor has been renewed by an outside agent, nor with the present participle that the action is reflexive. The difference is between the completed and the ongoing.

Comment: I think it has to be past tense in "renewed vigor". Because first there is what was causing the renewal (maybe he ate lunch and took a long nap), and then the activity that improved as a result (what he was playing). But I don't think your examples follow the same context, since he is probably not renewing his vigor while he is playing.

Comment: @user3169: In *with renewed vigor*  the word **renewed** is not a simple past. Compare "with renewed commitment".  It is the past participle used adjectivally.  And I said that he was *not* renewing his own vigor ("no implication ... with the present participle that the action is reflexive").

Comment: @user3169:  *He had lost nearly all of his money playing poker and felt despondent. But he had a premonition that this was going to be a good hand. He played with renewing vigor as the dealer dealt him an ace, then another, and then yet another.*